# Is there a way to find words for less popular readings of kanji?

Tags: kanji

Let's take  文  kanji for example:

I can find words for its most popular readings -　もん、ぶん、ふみ：

文字、文化、文、文人【ふみひと】

But [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%96%87#Japanese)  it says there are two other readings -  あや and  かざる - but i can't find words for them!! (google, wiktionary, jisho.org do not help!)

Or kanji  局 - wiktionary [mentions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B1%80#Japanese) this reading  しきる

But where is it used that way??

The question is  How can i find words for these less popular readings?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what your purpose is?

Comment: @snailboat: Curiosity would be a valid reason :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have *a solution*, albeit not a good one.

I only know of one way of doing this, and it isn't free. On my iPhone I have an app called "Japanese" - a Japanese dictionary. This app is not free, but I'm sure **there are other free (web)apps that can do the same things this app does**. I just don't have any experience with those apps. The feature I'm talking about is allowing you to select single kanji, and see compound words or phrases containing this kanji. Just by looking up 文 and scrolling to the あや reading I can give you the following examples:

文を付ける(to make a false accusation)、文目(pattern, design)、美しい文(beautiful design).

Comment: It's just a thin layer over Jim Breen's EDICT and related dictionaries, which are freely available for download.  There are a number of freely available interfaces to the same data, including Jim Breen's own WWWJDIC, as well as the popular jisho.org.

Comment: The excellent [Aedict](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.baka.aedict) on Android can do this too. Free.

Answer (score 1):

Searching Japanese language dictionaries/dictionary aggregate sites like weblio.jp / kotobank.jp will usually will give you most of those readings.

On Kotobank, 文 gives separate entries for あや, ぶん, もん and ふみ. かざる shows up in the KANJIDIC2 but not for 文's entry. However, Kotobank's [飾(かざ)る entry](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A3%BE%E3%82%8B?dic=daijisen&oid=03182900) lists examples using 文(かざ)る under 下接句. (It seems to be limited to the phrase 過ちを文る - the ateji related to usage in the Analects of Confucius).